# How do I make my axis ticks face Inwards in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I have made a barplot using ggplot2 and the Journal I need to submit to requires that the axis ticks face inwards.

This is the my data

```
Mean.Inc.melt <- data.frame(
  Var1 = factor(rep(c("Harvest", "Pre-Harvest"), 3)),
  Var2 = factor(rep(c("Dip A", "Trip A", "Trip B"), each = 2L)),
  value = c(2, 34, 1, 36, 3, 46)
)
```

Including the standard error

```
SEM.Inc.melt <- data.frame(
  Var1 = factor(rep(c("Harvest", "Pre-Harvest"), 3)),
  Var2 = factor(rep(c("Dip A", "Trip A", "Trip B"), each = 2L)),
  value = c(1, 12, 1, 2, 1, 6)
)
```

This is the script I have used so far to create the plot:

```
ggplot(Mean.Inc.melt,aes(x=Var2,y=value,fill=Var1))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position=position_dodge(),colour='black')+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#000000','#FFFFFF'))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Mean.Inc.melt$value-SEM.Inc.melt$value,
                    ymax=Mean.Inc.melt$value+SEM.Inc.melt$value),width=.1,
                    position=position_dodge(.9))+
  xlab('Treatment')+
  ylab('Percentage Incidence (%)')+
  ylim(0,60)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0),limits=c(0,60))+
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.line=element_line(colour='black'),panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank(),
        panel.background=element_blank())+
  geom_vline(xintercept=0)+theme(legend.position='none')
```

I guess the point is - does anyone know if there a way I can get my axis to face inwards?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

While I don't understand journals' desire to have tick marks on the inside, it's quite straightforward to achieve this with `ggplot`.

The `axis.ticks.length` argument to [`theme`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html) allows you to set the length of tick marks. If this is set to a negative value, tick marks will be plotted inwards. For example (reposting a solution by Dennis Murphy [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.ggplot2/9317)):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + geom_point() + 
  theme(axis.ticks.length=unit(-0.25, "cm"))
```

[image]

Note that the value should be passed as a `unit` object, which requires that the `grid` package (pre-installed with R) is loaded.

Comment: In ggplot 2.0.0 having a `Warning message: 'axis.ticks.margin' is deprecated. Please set 'margin' property  of 'axis.text' instead` -- and it seems `axis.text = element_text(margin=5)` does not help... I will post back if the solutions googles up.

Comment: So, according to test-and-try method, this is how you do it now: `theme(axis.ticks.length=unit(-0.25, "cm"), axis.text.x = element_text(margin=unit(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm")), axis.text.y = element_text(margin=unit(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm")) )` -- somehow it didn't inherit the setting from `axis.text`, and the error messages prompt for margin to be a vector of lengths 4.