# How to create cross tick marks in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a line graph in ggplot2 that has tick marks that crosses the axis, rather than just inside or outside of it.

My current code is:

```r
library(ggplot2)    
data("economics", package = "ggplot2")

ggplot(economics, aes(x = date, y = uempmed)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq.Date(from = as.Date("1968-12-31"), to = as.Date("1978-12-31"), by = "12 months"),
               limits = as.Date(c("1968-01-01", "1978-12-31")), labels = scales::date_format("%y")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(4,10)) +
  theme_bw()
```

This gives me the following result:

[image]

I can get the ticks to be inside or outside when creating my own theme, but not both simultaneously.

Here is an example of what I am attempting to accomplish:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question and I found an alternate solution that seems to work well. All you have to do is use `c(-length, length)` for your tick length. See example code below.

```
library(ggplot2)    
data("economics", package = "ggplot2")

ggplot(economics, aes(x = date, y = uempmed)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq.Date(from = as.Date("1968-12-31"), to = as.Date("1978-12-31"), by = "12 months"),
               limits = as.Date(c("1968-01-01", "1978-12-31")), labels = scales::date_format("%y")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(4,10)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.ticks.length.x=unit(c(-2.5,2.5), "pt"))
```

Answer (score 2):

First, seems like you already know: [How do I make my axis ticks face Inwards in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367296/how-do-i-make-my-axis-ticks-face-inwards-in-ggplot2)

But can tick marks cross the axis? **Turns out, no, they can't.**

Here's the relevant piece from the [`ggplot2` Github repo](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/86cc4d27001a3354326042acb690e2a4cfa4e8d6/R/guides-axis.r#L273-L281). You'll see that the segment is always drawn starting from the axis.

There might be a `ggplot2` extension that makes this easy, but none that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

That's possible with a mild hack. Fake the ticks with annotation.

```r
library(ggplot2)    

date_breaks <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("1968-12-31"), to = as.Date("1978-12-31"), by = "12 months")

ggplot(economics) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = uempmed)) + 
  geom_text(data = data.frame(x = date_breaks, y = -Inf),
            aes(x, y, label= '|')) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks,
               limits = as.Date(c("1968-01-01", "1978-12-31")), 
               labels = scales::date_format("%y")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(4,10)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme_bw(base_rect_size = 0.1) +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
#> Warning: Removed 442 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>