# Adjusting the y-tick labels with hjust not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to move the y-axis tick labels to the left (as i did with the axis.text.y to the bottom).

The weird thing is with `hjust = -2.5`, although the `theme_set()` part runs without errors, the text on the y-axis does not get moved. However, `vjust = 2`does affect the y labels just fine.

I am creating a bug with all my options in the theme?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2) 
theme_set(
    theme_classic() + 
        theme(
            axis.ticks.length = unit(-0.25, "cm"),
            axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = -2.5),
            axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = -2.5), # this does not do anything.
#            axis.text.y = element_text(vjust = -2.5), # while vjust does affect the text placement.
            axis.line = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major.y = element_line(linetype = 2),
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
            text = element_text(family = "serif"),
            legend.justification = c(1, 1),
            legend.position = c(1, 1),
            panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, size = 2))) 
mpgdat <- tibble(mtcars)
mpgdat %>% ggplot(aes(disp, mpg)) + geom_point()
```

Answer (score 0):

This does seem to be a [bug in how hjust works for axis text](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1435). A workaround would be to use `margin` instead of `hjust`:

```
theme_set(
  theme_classic() + 
    theme(
      axis.ticks.length = unit(-0.25, "cm"),
      axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = -2.5),
      axis.text.y = element_text(margin = unit(c(0,0.4,0,0), "cm")),
      panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, size = 2)))
```

[image]'

Hat tip to this related answer: [How do I make my axis ticks face Inwards in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367296/how-do-i-make-my-axis-ticks-face-inwards-in-ggplot2)